# Convert ODBC Datasource to .MDB file

Tags: c#, odbc

I currently have a database connected to ODBC using the DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver.
I need a way to convert this database into an .MDB access database file using code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing it in 2 steps:

1. Conversion of database schema. In this step create SQL file with `CREATE TABLE` commands with info from your database source. Some data types may be different in your source and it may be hard to convert it to MS Access. Try to run such SQL commands on MS Access and correct errors until your schema looks identical (the same names of tables and columns, identical or very similar data types).
2. Copy data. Now you have identical or very similar schema on both sides. Now export source data to destination table. There are many ways of doing it. I prefer Jython with JDBC drivers, PreparedStatement with `INSERT` and code that looks like:

   ```
   insert_stmt.setObject(i, rs_in.getObject(i))
   ```

This will work with ODBC while in JDK 1.7 and earlier there is JDBC-ODBC bridge (it disappeared in JDK 1.8). I think that in `.NET` environment it is very similar.